# Spring 18 <lightning:datatable> Issue with Actions

Tags: lightning-datatable

I am facing an issue with the actions(Show Details, Delete). The Action dropdown is hidden inside the table instead of showing all actions. PFB screenshot. Did anyone face this issue?

[image]
Below screenshot is taken from standard Account Recent view. Its showing all Actions (Edit, Delete, Change Owner) 
[image]

Component:

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="mydata" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{! c.init }"/>
<lightning:datatable data="{! v.mydata }"
                     columns="{! v.mycolumns }"
                     keyField="Id"
                     hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                     onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"
                     showRowNumberColumn="true"/>
```

Controller:

```
({
init: function (cmp, event, helper) {

    var actions = [
        { label: 'Show details', name: 'show_details' },
        { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' }
    ];

    cmp.set('v.mycolumns', [
            {type:  'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions } },
            {label: 'Opportunity name', fieldName: 'opportunityName', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Confidence', fieldName: 'confidence', type: 'percent', cellAttributes:
                { iconName: { fieldName: 'trendIcon' }, iconPosition: 'right' }},
            {label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency', typeAttributes: { currencyCode: 'EUR'}},
            {label: 'Contact Email', fieldName: 'contact', type: 'email'},
            {label: 'Contact Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone'}
    ]);
    cmp.set('v.mydata', [{
            id: 'a',
            opportunityName: 'Cloudhub',
            confidence: 0.2,
            amount: 25000,
            contact: 'jrogers@cloudhub.com',
            phone: '2352235235',
            trendIcon: 'utility:down'
    },
    {
            id: 'b',
            opportunityName: 'Quip',
            confidence: 0.78,
            amount: 740000,
            contact: 'quipy@quip.com',
            phone: '2352235235',
            trendIcon: 'utility:up'
    }]);
},
getSelectedName: function (component, event, helper) {
    var selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');
    // Display that fieldName of the selected rows
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++){
        alert("You selected: " + selectedRows[i].Name);
    }
},
handleRowAction: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    var action = event.getParam('action');
    var row = event.getParam('row');
    switch (action.name) {
        case 'show_details':
            alert('Showing Details: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
            break;
        case 'delete':
            var rows = cmp.get('v.data');
            var rowIndex = rows.indexOf(row);
            rows.splice(rowIndex, 1);
            cmp.set('v.data', rows);
            break;
    }
}
```

})

Comment: from your screenshot I can see the first action: `Show Details` - only the second one is missing right?

Comment: exactly. It also depends on no. of records of the table if table height (rows) is more than Action dropdown height then it is showing all actions otherwise based on the height of the table, showing the action. In my case there are only 2 actions, 1 visible and other not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already an answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209402/lightningdatatable-not-rendering-correctly), this is what you need to do:

Add this code:

```
.THIS .slds-scrollable_x { overflow: visible; }
.THIS .slds-scrollable_y { overflow: visible; }
```

to your style component bundle:

[image]